# Como instalar o Opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

eu gostaria de saber como faz para instalar a ultima versão do Opencv 3.2 no linux ubuntu 14.04. Eu consegui instalar e colocar para compilar no codeblocks usando C++ seguindo um tutorial. Mas meu objetivo é realmente instalar a biblioteca opencv para que eu use ela com a linguagem python e possa rodar de boas o codigo. Eu nao entendi muito bem mas eu iria usar o impot do python para usar o opencv? alguem que conheça essa biblioteca poderia me dar umas dicas e me ajudar nisso? obrigado.

Obs: meu objetivo é reconhecimento de cor,e objetos.
Obs 2: eu gostaria de executar ele no atom ou no codeblocks.De preferencia no codeblocks.

Comment: Já [tentou](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python): `pip install opencv-python`

Comment: nao funcinou,nao parece existir uma bilioteca no pip do opencv

Comment: Eu utilizei [este tutorial em inglês](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) para o Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3):

Procure pelo pacote opencv em python com o pip, no exemplo abaixo estou em um ubuntu 16, em uma env python3:

```
~$ pip search opencv | grep "^opencv"
opencv-python-armv7l (3.2.0)     - opencv-python on armv7l.
opencv-contrib-python (3.2.0.7)  - Wrapper package for OpenCV python bindings.
opencv-cython (0.4)              - An alternative OpenCV wrapper
opencv-utils (0.0.2)             - OpenCV Utilities
opencv-python (3.2.0.7)          - Wrapper package for OpenCV python bindings.
opencv_cffi (0.2.2)              - A random subset of OpenCV's functionality, wrapped via CFFI
opencv_engine (1.0.1)            - OpenCV imaging engine for thumbor.
opencv_helpers (1.1)             - Helper functions for opencv
opencvutils (0.9.2)              - Simple OpenCV 3.x image processing functions
```

Nesse caso vamos instalar o quarto item:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Ou [instale o anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) e acabe com todos os problemas de pacotes. :-)

### Exemplo de uso

Capturando um video:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Este exemplo foi retirado da otima documentação do pacote, há [uma área de tutoriais](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) muito boa com vários exercícios, divirta-se.

Answer (score 0):

Instala o [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

Instala o OpenCV 3 rodando este comando no prompt do anaconda:

`conda install -c menpo opencv3`

Testei no Windows 10 e Ubuntu 14.

fonte: https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3